# Maria DB slow query log not writing anything

Tags: mariadb

For some reason, the Maria DB (version 10.1) slow query log is not writing anything.  I've enabled slow query logging:

```
select @@slow_query_log, @@slow_query_log_file, @@long_query_time, @@log_output;

| 1 | /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log | 3.000000 | FILE |
```

I can trigger a slow query and see that it is being noted:

```
select sleep(5);
show status like 'Slow_queries%';

| Slow_queries | 1 |
```

But when I check the slow query log in `/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log`, it is empty.

Comment: sleep() does not increment slow_queries. Run an actual slow query to see something logged.

Comment: Are you sure?  Other resources have specified that's the way to test the slow query log: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7777/write-a-slow-query-to-test-slow-query-logging.  It's definitely affecting the slow_queries status.

Comment: I just tried it for myself on an actual running MariaDB 10.2.20 database before posting the comment. Maybe it worked in 2011, but it isn't today.

Comment: When you say you tried it, do you mean it's NOT updating `Slow_queries`?  Or just that it does not write to the log file?

Comment: I mean that slow_queries does not change. And of course nothing is written to the log.

Comment: OK, then this seems to be a difference between Maria DB 10.1 and 10.2.  It's most definitely updating the `Slow_queries` on 10.1.

Comment: I would guess it's not meant to. It's rather pointless to log a sleep() as a slow query, after all.

Comment: Do things work if you change `log_output` to `TABLE`?